# regarding External entry point

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, test-setup

i have one custom field called Unique_Vendor_Id__c on account object (external id checkbox checked) and its auto-number.

now in test class when i create account for test data Unique_Vendor_Id__c should be automatically created as soon as account created, and in controller i am fetching data from that Unique_Vendor_Id__c if available.

now when i run test class it gives me following error :

```
System.StringException: Invalid id: null
```

and in stack trace :

```
External entry point Class.VendorAndChargeCreationControllerTest.VendorAndChargeCreationControllerTestMethod1: line 45, column 1
```

so from this error i think autonumber field is not generating id at a time of account creation am i right?

please let me know do i have to change any thing in field for generating that autonumber field in test data?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you haven't supplied any code this is only a guess based on a typical problem...

When something happens in the database changed field values (with the exception of object `Id` fields when records are created) are *not* automatically brought back into the Apex code. So you have to *requery* the data to see the new values.

Comment: yes that was the problem, i mean it wasn't returning full object with auto number and other fields thats why it was coming null, now i query that record and boom got the data. thank you very much.

Comment: @Keith C , i am also getting the same, but in my case i have custom fields, with unique checked. in the debug logs i have checked it's not null.when it comes page it saying: Invalid id: 00013
Error is in expression '{!method1}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page SomeClassName: External entry point,  <--- custom_object__c (text,unique checked).

Comment: okay i found, the mapping key issue i was checking with another custom_field1__c as a key, actually it was custom_field2__c as key of the map

Comment: I got this error before because I was using doing System.runAs(<user does not exist>). So just had to update the test class to make it work again